# Xamarin Forms TranslateTo Animation works one time only

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app and currently, I am improving the user experience of the app. I have added the following code for animation. The problem is it works one time only on the device. Works well on Simulator. What can be the problem? It would be great if someone finds out the problem.

```
var gestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        gestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
        {
                var task1 = this.PlaceHolderTextLabel.TranslateTo(0, -12, 250, Easing.SinInOut);
                var task2 = this.InputControl.TranslateTo(0, 6, 250, Easing.SinInOut);
                await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { task1, task2 });

                this.InputControl.IsEnabled = true;
                this.InputControl.Focus();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TranslationX` and `TranslationY` each time, because the position of the view changes every time.But you can get the the X or Y translation delta of the element by `TranslationX` and `TranslationY`.

For example, you can use like this:

```
var task1 = this.mLabel.TranslateTo(0, mLabel.TranslationY - 12, 250, Easing.SinInOut);
var task2 = this.mInputView.TranslateTo(0, mInputView.TranslationY + 6, 250, Easing.SinInOut);
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { task1, task2 });
```

For more information about this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.translationx?view=xamarin-forms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.translationy?view=xamarin-forms